# how return array in java script console

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console.log

i have this array  `a =['Mona','Hebe,'hi-fa']` and i want to print all the name in one message
that be return an array of message
i try this :

```js
let name=[];

function names(name,word)
{
   for(let i=0;i<name.length;i++)
   {
    return `Hi , ${name[i]},You are ${word} girl`;
   }
 
}

names(['Mona','Hebe,'hi-fa'], 'amazing' ) ;
```

the result should be Hi Mona You are amazing girl ,  Hi Hebe You are amazing girl,Hi hi-fa You are amazing girl

Comment: You're missing a quote after `Hebe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted it all in 1 line, so I concat it all in a new text variable before i put it at the end out. Without for the first line I added before a space for seperating the sentences.

You forget one quotationmark after Hebe. Used in your template event instead of word, which is your function parameter.

```js
let name=[];

function names(name,word)
{
   let text = "";
   for(let i=0;i<name.length;i++)
   {
     if (i!==0)
         text += ' ';
     text+=(`Hi, ${name[i]},You are ${word} girl.`);
   }
   
   console.log(text);
   
   return name;
}

names(['Mona','Hebe','hi-fa'], 'amazing' ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you are missing a quote after `Hebe`. Next, you had `event` as your string literal, but your variable was `word`.

```js
let name=[];

function names(name,word)
{
   for(let i=0;i<name.length;i++)
   {
    console.log(`Hi ${name[i]}. You are an ${word} girl.`);
   }
   return name;
}

names(['Mona','Hebe','hi-fa'], 'amazing' ) ;
```

This can also be written without the `for` loop or the empty `name` array using the [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, which eliminates the need for you to manage a loop counter and makes it simpler to access the item being iterated:

```js
function listNames(names,word,gender){
  names.forEach(function(name){ 
    console.log(`Hi ${name}. You are ${word} ${gender}.`);
  });
}

listNames(['Mona','Hebe','hi-fa'], 'an amazing', 'girl') ;
listNames(['Tony','Troy','Steve'], 'a bad', 'boy') ;
```

Comment: how can return this array message  ? i mean without use console

Comment: @Pop Just replace console with return (a space) and the string.

Comment: but do not type all array

Answer (score 0):

Change event for your second parameter

```
let name=[];

function names(name,word)
{
   for(let i=0;i<name.length;i++)
   {
    console.log(`Hi , ${name[i]},You are ${word} girl`);
   }
   return name;
}

names(['Mona','Hebe,'hi-fa'], 'amazing' ) ;
```